# How to change part of the border to a different color in a table?

Tags: html, css

```css
.table {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 210px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .table-year-1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 2%;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }
  .table-year-2 {
    width: 2%;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }

  .table-head-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }
  
  .bk{
    font-size:23px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .top-table-text{
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  
  table .tr-border{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4f91d8;
  }
  table .tr-border-top{
    border-top: 1px solid #4f91d8;
  }
  
 .spacer{
    display: table-cell;
   width: 3%;  
  }

  td {
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">2018</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment Securities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Loans (net of valuation reserve)<br />
        ($28,582 in 2018 &amp; $27,063 in 2017)</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,902,960</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,813,062</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Federal Funds Sold</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accured Income</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Funds</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$190,104</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$179,582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$370,094</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$274,994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,857,311</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,542,877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">$22,497</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">$22,954</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fed Funds Purchase &amp; Other Borrowed Money</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$63,394</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,879,808</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,629,225</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Capital 
          Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capital Stock</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surplus</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Undivided Proﬁts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span">(Loss) 
          Securities</span></td>
        <td class="table-year-1">($15,384)</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">($5,558)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$276,232</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$253,898</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text bk">Total Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break-2">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break-2">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've created a table with borders on certain sections. I need to change the bottom border to white (where it meets to the blue and grey section). Right now the border is all one color.
I'm trying to add the white so there looks like there is some separation.
The picture below shows the what i'm trying to get too. The border is blue, then under the blue and grey sections on certain parts its white to show separation.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOtW.png)

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">2018</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment Securities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Loans (net of valuation reserve)<br />
        ($28,582 in 2018 &amp; $27,063 in 2017)</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,902,960</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,813,062</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Federal Funds Sold</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accured Income</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Funds</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$190,104</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$179,582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$370,094</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$274,994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,857,311</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,542,877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">$22,497</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">$22,954</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fed Funds Purchase &amp; Other Borrowed Money</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$63,394</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,879,808</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,629,225</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Capital 
          Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capital Stock</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surplus</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Undivided Proﬁts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span">(Loss) 
          Securities</span></td>
        <td class="table-year-1">($15,384)</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">($5,558)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$276,232</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$253,898</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text bk">Total Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break-2">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break-2">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot the picture

Comment: Can you put the css code?

Comment: Have you looked at the Mozilla Developer Network documentation for styling boxes and styling tables?

Comment: I've added the css and added the example picture

Comment: Underneath the numbers where there is a border i'm trying to make that part white then keep everything else the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tr is the table row, so the border bottom line will be the width of the table. To match your image, you'll need to target the individual cell's (td's) instead.

Looks like you're very close. For example change `table .tr-border` to `table .tr-border td`. Then you can add rules to target `table .tr-border .table-year-1` and `table .tr-border .table-year-2`

Producing something like the following?

```css
.table {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 210px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .table-year-1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 2%;
    padding-top: 3px;
    background-color: #4f91d8;
  }
  .table-year-2 {
    width: 2%;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    background-color: #CCC;
  }

  .table-head-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }
  
  .bk{
    font-size:23px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .top-table-text{
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  
  table .tr-border td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4f91d8;
  }

  table .tr-border .table-year-1 {
     background-color: #4f91d8;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  }

  table .tr-border .table-year-2 {
     background-color: #CCC;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  }
  
 .spacer{
    display: table-cell;
   width: 3%;  
  }

  td {
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">2018</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment Securities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Loans (net of valuation reserve)<br />
        ($28,582 in 2018 &amp; $27,063 in 2017)</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,902,960</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,813,062</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Federal Funds Sold</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accured Income</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Funds</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$190,104</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$179,582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$370,094</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$274,994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,857,311</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,542,877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">$22,497</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">$22,954</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fed Funds Purchase &amp; Other Borrowed Money</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$63,394</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,879,808</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,629,225</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Capital 
          Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capital Stock</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surplus</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Undivided Proﬁts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span">(Loss) 
          Securities</span></td>
        <td class="table-year-1">($15,384)</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">($5,558)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$276,232</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$253,898</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text bk">Total Liabilities &amp; 
          Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break-2">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break-2">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes! I was close! Thanks!